# setting low rlimit_nproc value doesn't allow even a single fork

Tags: c, fork, setrlimit

I am trying to use setrlimit to limit the number of processes a program can create. Here is my code:

```
struct rlimit limiter;
getrlimit( RLIMIT_NPROC, &limiter );
limiter.rlim_max = limiter.rlim_cur = 10;
setrlimit( RLIMIT_NPROC, &limiter );

int val = fork();
printf( "Error number %d\n", errno ); //gives 11
if( val == -1 ) {
    printf( "Fork failed\n" );
} else if( val ) {
    printf( "parent\n" );
} else {
    printf("child\n" );
}
return 0;
```

Since the value of `rlim_max` and `rlim_cur` is 10, my program should be allowed to fork 10 processes. But right now it is failing even for a single fork call. Though it works if I set the values to around 250. I don't understand why is that. I want a way to limit the number of forks to `n`.

Comment: Does your user already have running processes that count towards the limit?

Comment: Well, I am running this program with the same user as the one I am logged in with, so yes i guess ?

Comment: Well, there you go. `man getrlimit/setrlimit, RLIMIT_NPROC The maximum number of processes (or, more  precisely  on  Linux, threads) that can be created for the real user ID of the calling process.  Upon encountering this limit, fork(2) fails  with  the error EAGAIN.`. I guess you could create a separate user to execute your program?

Comment: I can do that, but it would still work incorrectly if the separate user starts another program. How could I limit the number of processes by started by _this_ program ?